# Get factors of a number

Tags: php, numbers, factors

I need to get two factors ( x, y ) of a given number ( n ) such that:

- x * y <= n
- x * y should be as close to n as possible
- x and y should be as close to each other as possible.

Examples:

- n = 16 => x = 4, y = 4
- n = 17 => x = 4, y = 4
- n = 18 => x = 6, y = 3
- n = 20 => x = 5, y = 4

Any language will do but preferably php.

EDIT -- CLARIFICATION

I want to create a rectangle, x units wide * y units tall such that its area is as close to n as possible. x and y must be integers. If n is a prime number then factors of n - 1 are acceptable.

Comment: Question is kinda of misleading. 4 is not a factor of 17.

Comment: He is not asking for a way to factorize numbers.

Comment: @badp: I know, and that's exactly why I said using the word "factor" is misleading. The question title is "get factors of a number" and it starts with "I need to get two factors of a given number". But he doesn't really want factors.

Comment: For 57 would you choose 7*8 or 3*19?

Comment: (3, 19) as these are factors multiply up perfectly. For 18 we have (3, 6) and (2, 9) -- (3, 6) are closer hence chosen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your specifications weren't quite exact enough. You stated that you wanted factors, yet in your test case 4 *is not* a factor of 17

The following pseudo code works prioritizing that one factor is *exact*

```
for i in range(ceiling(sqrt(n)), 1){
    if ( n modulo i ) == 0 {
          x = i
          y = round(n/i)
    }
}
```

Where as a simple  sqrt statement will work for ensuring that the numbers are as close together as possible, but doesn't guarantee that they are factors.

```
x = y = round( sqrt(n) )
```

Comment: That is because the test case where n = 17 is inconsistant with the rest of the test cases. All other test cases have x and y as factors, where as 17 doesn't for an unspecified reason.

Comment: This and all answers along these lines are OK except that that prime numbers are to be treated as special case (as mentioned by Dor).

Answer (score 4):

You need to decide how important your three rules are.

**Possibility 1:** If x * y being as close to n as possible is true then n=17 => 1,17 not 4,4. In this case you want factorisation and there are lots of ways to do it, but code like this is simple:

```
for(i = floor(sqrt(n)) .. 1) {
  if n % i ==0 {
     x = i;
     y = n/x;
     break;
  }
}
```

**Possibility 2:** If being close to each other is more important you'd expect n=18=>4,4 rather than 3,6, and this code would work. This however is not factors.

```
x=floor(sqrt(n))
y=floor(n/x)
```

The problem as written is unsolvable without a clearer specification.

**EDIT** ------------

Now the spec has been edited it is now defined, but you need to do Possibility 1, see if the result is prime (1 is one of the values) and then if it is repeat doing Possibility 2. However, I doubt this is what whichever teacher wrote this as homework intended.

Answer (score 1):

An idea from me (more pseudo then php)

```
$root = sqrt($inputNumber);

$x = floor($root);
$y = floor($root);

if(($root - $x) > 0.5) $y++;
```

Comment: I think you want the `floor` function in PHP.

Comment: Instead of RountToZero, call it floor :) That's a common function with the described functionality and thus it's easier to recognize

Answer (score 1):

```
$num = ...; // some number

if (is_prime($num)) // implement the is_prime() function yourself
    --$num; // Subtract to get an even number, which is not a prime

$candidates = array();  // Numbers that may fit.

$top_search = $num / 2; // Limits the useless search for candidates

for($i=1; $i < $top_search; ++$i)
{
    if ($num % $i == 0)
        $candidates[$i] = $num / $i;
}

// Now, check the array in the middle
```

Comment: Thanks, the "prime number case" is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have all the factors written to an array using the following code.

```
#Application lists all factors/divisors for a number.
targetNumber=input('What number do you want the factors for?\n> ')
factors=[]
for i in range(1,targetNumber):
    if targetNumber%i==0:
        factors.append(i)
    elif targetNumber/i==1:
        factors.append(targetNumber)
        break
print factors
```

Then I'd loop through the array to check which ones can actually be used. For more on this algorithm, check out http://pyfon.blogspot.com.au/2012/09/list-factors-of-number-in-python.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a PHP function that prioritize the two 'factors' being close to each other over having exact factors:

```
function weird_factors($ori) {
    $sq = intval(sqrt($ori));
    $start = $sq - 10;
    $end = $sq + 10;
    $n = 0;
    for ($s = $start; $s <= $end; $s++) {
        for ($t = $start; $t <= $end; $t++) {
            $st = $s * $t;
            if ($st <= $ori and $st > $n) {
                $n = $st;
                $ns = $s;
                $nt = $t;
            }
        }
    }
    return array($ns, $nt);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a program to find factor of any number

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub']))
 {     $j=0;
   $factor=array(); 
   $num=$_POST['nm1'];
   for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++)  
       {
          if($num%$i==0)
            { 
             $j++;
             $factor[$j]=$i;
            }
       }
}
 ?>

 <table>
 <form name="frm" method="post" action="">
 <tr> <td>Number:</td> <td><input type="text" name="nm1" /></td> </tr>
 <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" name="sub" /></td>
 <td><center><span>  
  <?php   
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))  
    { 
       echo "Factors are :";for($i=1;$i<=count($factor);$i++) 
       {          echo $factor[$i].",";

        }
     }       
  ?>   
   </span></center></td></tr>
 </form>
 </table>
```