# Checking a number's factor

Tags: php, division

I'm not sure if this title is correct but here's basically what I am trying to do.

I am trying to check if a number is less than 100 and if it isn't I would like to know what factor of 10 I need to divide it by to get below 100 i.e. for 7923 the factor is 100 to make it 79.23 and for 452,936,489 the factor would be 10,000,000 to make it 45.2936489.

Is there a function or a piece of script that does that out there?

Cheers

Comment: Or you can just count the digits and if it's more than 2, return 10 ^ (digits - 2) ?

Comment: Thank you Brandon. I assume there is no function for that?

Comment: @andrewsi win. seriously, make it an answer and i will upvote it.

Comment: Sorry Andrew I'm not quite sure where you're coming from?

Comment: there is no built in function i dont' believe

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860339/get-factors-of-a-number

Comment: @JamesGardner - a 3 digit number needs dividing by 10. A 4 digit number needs dividing by 100 (10^2). So an x-digit number will need dividing by 10^(x-2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$number = 452936489;
$factor = pow(10, ceil(log($number/100) / log(10)));
```

Ok. basic math:

you need to find a power of 10 divisor that reduces your number below 100, so the log business figures out the exact fractional power of 10 required to turn 10 into your original number. That comes out to be around 6.6560373....

That gets rounded up to 7, and is then used to raise 10 to that power.

```
10^7 = 10,000,000
452936489 / 10^7 = 45.2936489
```

Comment: So explain what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks Marc but that returns 1 as a factor

Comment: Ok. now the math's straight. Haven't had morning tea yet, so brain's fuzzy

Comment: Ah brilliant thank you Marc! Just 1 question, is there a way to check the factor for less than 100 not less than 10? Thank you so much

Comment: LOL. "This function will convert all input to a number, even non-scalar values, which could lead to ***weird*** results." - http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php

Comment: Thanks Marc but when I run the script I get 10^8 :| Is it me being a dumbass?

Comment: LOL. "Basic math." I think I'll start adding that in my code comments when I'm writing out Quantum Physics equations in PHP...

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ: log base conversion is taught in grade 9/10 algebra in these parts.

Comment: Go Canada! That's excellent. I'm from "the South" and they teach us to use calculators. Not really what they're doing, just how to hit the buttons. Figured it would be helpful if you explained it for the kiddies.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$num = 7923;
$x = 10;
while(true)
{
    $result = $num/$x;
    if($result < 100) 
    {
        die($x.""); 
    }
    else
    {
        $x *= 10;
    }
}
?>
```